# PVR/DVR Software

Tags: usb, media-manager

We're cutting the cable and putting up an antenna. I have a not-too-old laptop I plan on using as a DVR (or PVR - not sure what the difference is), and have an inexpensive [USB TV tuner](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0084363Z6) on order. Any suggestions for software?

Currently the PC has Windows 7 with [Media Center](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/products/windows-media-center). I was looking at [MythTV](https://www.mythtv.org/) - it seems pretty full-featured (installing Linux on the laptop shouldn't be an issue). But I have no experience with either of these.

Desired features:

- Auto record shows
- Pause/Rewind Live TV
- Act as a server - other PCs on network can access recordings
- HD

Optional features:

- iPad app to access recordings
- Media server for my videos/pictures/music
- DVD/Blu-ray grabber - store copies of my DVDs on disk
- Work with multiple USB tuners - watch and record at same time
- Netflix/Amazon Prime Integration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow up (since nobody answered).

I ended up going with [NextPVR](http://nextpvr.com/). I didn't go with MediaCenter since Microsoft has abandoned it. I did not use MythTV because the tuner card I purchased did not have a Linux driver (I ended up returning it but was already using NPVR on Windows 7). NPVR has most of the features I needed.

With all the PVR software I've looked at there are 2 parts: a front end and a back end. The back end manages recordings and stuff, and the front end is the user interface. I have been playing with NPVR as the back end and [Kodi](https://kodi.tv/) as the front end. As of yet, I have not decided on NPVR's front end or Kodi. NPVR is nice and simple, but I have a Raspberry PI 2 set up as a 2nd PVR in the bedroom and NPVR isn't available for Linux but Kodi is both Windows and Linux. So Kodi has the advantage of consistency - both PVRs have same UI.

Lastly, I originally purchased a $35 USB tuner. It picked up only half the stations my TV did. I ended up going with [HDHomerun](https://www.silicondust.com/). It's more expensive but it has 2 tuners and gets all the channels as my TV so I feel it's worth it. I live 50 miles from the nearest city. YMMV.